# SQL with join two and order by limit

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that returns the following table:

```
(select trace_3733_3742.Sequance,trace_3733_3742.MainSequenceNum,trace_3733_3742.hopAddress addr from `trace_3733_3742` where MainSequenceNum = 5668799415 or MainSequenceNum = 5671689631);


+----------+-----------------+------------+
| Sequance | MainSequenceNum | addr       |
+----------+-----------------+------------+
|        1 |      5668799415 | 2229485073 | 
|        3 |      5668799415 | 2229496574 | 
|        4 |      5668799415 | 2258501244 | 
|        5 |      5668799415 | 3286073269 | 
|        6 |      5668799415 | 3241391462 | 
|        7 |      5668799415 | 3241390941 | 
|        8 |      5668799415 | 3241393449 | 
|        9 |      5668799415 | 3241393534 | 
|       10 |      5668799415 | 3561607085 | 
|       11 |      5668799415 |   71666625 |
```

...
...

and I have another table that using

```
(SELECT latitude,longitude FROM `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` WHERE (start_ip_num <= hopaddress) ORDER BY start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1);
```

hopaddress = one of the hopaddress from up table

for example :

```
(SELECT latitude,longitude FROM `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` WHERE (start_ip_num <= 3561607199) ORDER BY start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1);
```

will return the result i want

the table looks like :

```
+--------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| start_ip_num | end_ip_num | latitude | longitude |
+--------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|            0 |          0 |     NULL |      NULL | 
|     16777216 |   16777471 |      -27 |       133 | 
|     16777472 |   16778239 |       35 |       105 | 
|     16778240 |   16779263 |      -27 |       133 | 
|     16779264 |   16781311 |       35 |       105 | 
|     16781312 |   16785407 |       36 |       138 |
```

...
...

what i want to do is to return a query for the first table with latitude,longitude for each row - but i can't seem to do it

i tried the following :

```
select * from (select trace_3733_3742.Sequance,trace_3733_3742.MainSequenceNum,trace_3733_3742.hopAddress addr from `trace_3733_3742` where MainSequenceNum = 5668799415 or MainSequenceNum = 5671689631) trace
join GeoLiteCity_Oct2011 loc
where (loc.start_ip_num <= addr) ORDER BY loc.start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1
```

but it will only return 1 result and not all the table :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT m.Sequance,m.MainSequenceNum,m.hopAddress,
   (SELECT g.latitude,g.longitude FROM `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` AS g
    WHERE g.start_ip_num <= m.hopAddress
    ORDER BY g.start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1)
 FROM `trace_3733_3742` AS m
 WHERE m.MainSequenceNum = 5668799415 or m.MainSequenceNum = 5671689631;
```

Comment: its seem to work only if i try to get latitude or longitude if i try getting them both like you wrote "SELECT g.latitude,g.longitude" i get Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s) , how can i handle it ? Thanks!!

Comment: when i use "CONCAT(g.latitude,",",g.longitude)" it works , how can i bypass this ERROR?

Comment: SELECT m.Sequance,m.MainSequenceNum,m.hopAddress,
   (SELECT g.latitude FROM `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` AS g
    WHERE g.start_ip_num <= m.hopAddress
    ORDER BY g.start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT j.longitude FROM `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` AS j
    WHERE j.start_ip_num <= m.hopAddress
    ORDER BY j.start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1)
 FROM `trace_3733_3742` AS m
 WHERE m.MainSequenceNum = 5668799415 or m.MainSequenceNum = 5671689631;

that should make it... but probably not the best way of doing it

Comment: yes i thought about doing it , but its not efficient i prefer the concat and then deal with the result :) Thanks anyway .

Answer (score 0):

Providing that `start_ip_num` has unique values you can join `GeoLiteCity_Oct2011` table in order to get both `lattitude` and `longitude` for `start_ip_num` selected in your subquery:

```
SELECT Sequance, MainSequenceNum, hopAddress, latitude, longitude, geo.start_ip_num,
   (SELECT start_ip_num FROM GeoLiteCity_Oct2011
    WHERE start_ip_num <= hopAddress
    ORDER BY start_ip_num DESC LIMIT 1) start_ip
FROM trace_3733_3742
JOIN GeoLiteCity_Oct2011 AS geo
WHERE MainSequenceNum = 5668799415 or MainSequenceNum = 5671689631
HAVING geo.start_ip_num = start_ip;
```